# ¿Cómo pasar 2 parámetros a controlador por href en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

en mi vista tengo el siguiente enlace:

```
<a href="/graph/show">
```

y en mi controlador tengo lo siguiente

```
def show
    @encuestas_graph=Encuestum.where("periodo=1 AND ano=2017")
end
```

Lo que quiero es pasarle al controlador los parámetros 'periodo' y 'ano', desde mi vista.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando erb templates, en general es recomendable que uses [`link_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-links) para agregar links.
Con esto, puedes hacer:

```
<%= link_to 'Mi link', graph_show_path(periodo: '1', ano: '2107' %>
```

para luego en tu controlador:

```
@encuestas_graph = Encuestum.where(periodo: params[:periodo], ano: params[:ano]")
```